# Do not add document to collection if already exist in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to omit adding/updating document if it was found in the collection without doing two requests to Mongo server? It would be perfect if this can be done in bulk, but I would appreciate to hear other options or workarounds.

What I'm looking for is sort of opposite of [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/) option:

```
var bulk = MyCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({ x: val }).upsertOnlyIfNotFound({ x: newVal });
bulk.execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [$setOnInsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/).

```
db.MyCollection.update(
  { x: val },
  {
     $setOnInsert: { x: "newVal" }
  },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

From the documentation :

> If an update operation with upsert: true results in an insert of a
>   document, then $setOnInsert assigns the specified values to the fields
>   in the document. If the update operation does not result in an insert,
>   $setOnInsert does nothing.

Comment: This does solve my issue, thank you!